# Combining multiple VARCHAR fields as 1 DATE when inserting from one table to another in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, toad, oracle12c

I'm attempting to create a short script which will take all of the fields from Table1 and insert them into Table2. The basic fields (col1, col2, col3, etc.) I have got covered by something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7)
             SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, SYSDATE, USER
FROM Table2
```

For `col8` and `col9` in Table1 I'm a little stuck though. `col8/col9` for instance are `DATE` datatypes which need to be inserted by combining `col6/col7/col8` and `col9/col10/col11` from Table1 respectively together. Each of these are defined as follows:

```
col6/col9  -- VARCHAR2 (2Byte) // Month
col7/col10 -- VARCHAR2 (2Byte) // Day
col8/col11 -- VARCHAR2 (4Byte) // Year
```

Looking online I tried the below, but receive `"not a valid month"`:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (......)
SELECT ...., TO_DATE(TOCHAR(col6, '00') || TO_CHAR(col7, '00') || TO_CHAR(col8, '9999'), 'MM/DD/YYYY'), .....
FROM Table 2
```

Does anyone know how to get what I'm after here and combine 3 specific VARCHAR fields as a DATE for insertion as 1 field in Table1?

Comment: The `not a valid month` error is due to your data.  I'm sure you'll have a 0 in your data for a month, or null perhaps.  Use coalesce and do some error handling on the values you are trying to convert.

Comment: @paqogomez, it appears you are correct. There are some records for these (2) 3-Column combinations with `00/00/0000` for the individual 3 fields. I'm not familiar with `Coalesce`; would you mind providing an example of what you mean? I'm assuming you are referring to some form of checking for `00/null` and if so setting a default data value?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on your data.  Coalesce just gives the first value that is not null in a set of values  `Coalesce(null, null, 1, 2 null)` returns `1`.  All that needs to happen here is that you need to scrub your data because 00/00/0000 will not ever be a valid date.  Consider either changing your original data to valid values, or restricting your query (in the where clause) to columns that dont contain invalid data.

Comment: Why are you using `to_char` if your source columns are already strings? Maybe you just wanted to left-pad the values with zeros, not convert them to numbers and back?

Comment: @paqogomez, do you have an example along the lines of `"If col6/col7/col8 == '00/00/0000' set Table2.col16 = 01/01/2000"`? So far I'm still stuck getting the 3 fields to combine for insertion to the 1 field. Using some other suggestions I've tried `TO_DATE(TO_TRIM(TO_CHAR(col6, 'FM00')) || TO_TRIM(TO_CHAR(col7, 'FM00')) || TO_TRIM(TO_CHAR(col8, 'FM9999')), 'MMDDYYYY')` but still get `not a valid date`.

Comment: @paqogomez, I tried `TO_DATE(TRIM(TO_CHAR(GREATEST(ABS(col6),12), 'FM00')) || TRIM(TO_CHAR(GREATEST(ABS(col7),12), 'FM00')) || TRIM(TO_CHAR(GREATEST(ABS(col8),12), 'FM9999')), 'MMDDYYYY')` and the values in my source table of `00|00|0000` individually become inserted in my new table as `12/12/0012`?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic - do you really want to set it to a fixed dummy value, rather than, say, leaving it null?

Comment: @AlexPoole, I suppose `null` would probably be the better solution, though I'm still not sure how to do the `check/insert null if true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the invalid values in your columns are always zeros, as you said in a comment, then you can use a fixed value - either a dummy date, or perhaps more reasonably leave the new column null - with a case statement:

```
SELECT ...., CASE
    WHEN TRIM('0' FROM col6) IS NULL OR TRIM('0' FROM col7) IS NULL
      OR TRIM('0' FROM col8) IS NULL THEN NULL
    ELSE TO_DATE(LPAD(col6, 2, '0') || LPAD(col7, 2, '0') || LPAD(col8, 4, '0'),
      'MMDDYYYY')
  END, ...
```

The TRIM removes zeros from the value and then checks if anything is left, which catches both 0 and 00 (and 000 and 0000 for col8) in one go.

The LPAD left-pads the value with zeros, so for example a value of 7 would become 07 - this is important because you need the concatenated values to match the date format model, and without leading zeros you'd end up with very confused and invalid results.

Note that I'm not using TO_CHAR at all. Since your source columns are already strings, you're actually doing an implicit conversion to a number, and then an explicit conversion back to a string. With the FM modifier or TRIM that would have the same effect as LPAD, but would be doing more work.

As a quick demo with some sample values in a CTE:

```
with t as (
  select '0' as col6, '0' as col7, '0' as col8 from dual
  union all select '00', '00', '0000' from dual
  union all select '08', '31', '2008' from dual
  union all select '7', '4', '2012' from dual
)
select col6, col7, col8,
  CASE
    WHEN TRIM('0' FROM col6) IS NULL OR TRIM('0' FROM col7) IS NULL
      OR TRIM('0' FROM col8) IS NULL THEN NULL
    ELSE TO_DATE(LPAD(col6, 2, '0') || LPAD(col7, 2, '0') || LPAD(col8, 4, '0'),
      'MMDDYYYY')
  END as my_date
from t;

COL6 COL7 COL8 MY_DATE  
---- ---- ---- ----------
0    0    0              
00   00   0000           
08   31   2008 2008-08-31
7    4    2012 2012-07-04
```

If you have other invalid values this will still trip over them - say, 09/31/2000, where the number of the days in the month is wrong. It isn't clear if that might be the case for your data. If it is then you could write a function to attempt to convert whatever is passed, and silently return null if it's invalid for any reason.

Comment: thanks! This is a well thought-out and document response. I'm not sure if it may be an issue, but in implementing this solution I did notice that `col6|col7|col8` with example value `08|31|2008` shows up in my new table `DATE` field as `8/31/2008` without the leading `0` for the month. For the moment I can't see it being an issue, but thought I would mention. Also, doing a quick check with `SELECT... WHERE TRIM(BOTH '0' FROM col6) ... col7/col8 it appears all the string values for these fields are valid other than those with 0/00/0000 inputted.

Comment: The date column in your table2 does not have any inherent format. Your client is presenting the date as a string, and is choosing not to show the leading zero. You can check with `select to_char(col8, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from table2`; using to_char here means you are formatting the date as a string, not leaving it up to the client.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure that this is what you are running into, but when I run

`SELECT TO_CHAR(1,'00') FROM dual;`

the output has an extra space in front of the expected `01`. I would wrap the call to `TO_CHAR()` in a call to `TRIM()` to remove any such spaces.

`SELECT TRIM(TO_CHAR(1,'00') FROM dual;`

I also noticed that your concatenation doesn't match the format mask you provide. Your format mask has separating `/`'s, but you are not concatenating those into your string. Your output at best would be `MMDDYYYY`. Consider adding that to your concatenation, or else changing your mask.

Comment: I would use the FM format modifier rather than trim, but the effect is the same. However, the source fields are strings, so I'm not sure why the OP could be calling to_char at all...

Comment: @HepC, I will give that a try. @AlexPoole, honestly pretty green when it comes to DB queries and next to no experience with Oracle (what little I have has been M$ products up to this point). Using `to_char` simply came from an example I saw in a slightly different thread.

Comment: I have tried the `FM` modifier as exampled below by DartXKey as well as adding `TRIM()` around my `TO_CHAR()` and am still receiving `not a valid month`? --- `TO_DATE(TO_TRIM(TO_CHAR(col6, 'FM00')) || TO_TRIM(TO_CHAR(col7, 'FM00')) || TO_TRIM(TO_CHAR(col8, 'FM9999')), 'MMDDYYYY')`

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (......) SELECT ...., TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(col6, 'FM00') || TO_CHAR(col7, 'FM00') || TO_CHAR(col8, 'FM9999'), 'MMDDYYYY'), ..... FROM Table 2
```

IMHO, this help. Your date format string was wrong, and to_char format too. Should work...

Comment: The following is still yielding `ORA-01843: not a valid month`...: `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(col6, 'FM00') || TO_CHAR(col7, 'FM00') || TO_CHAR(col8, 'FM9999'), 'MMDDYYYY')`

Comment: Are you sure, that col6 is between 0 and 12? Select distinct values, for interest.. or add something like ....to_char(greatest(abs(col6),12))....if you would like to ignore such mistakes..

Comment: Another side.. add /*+rule*/hint into select clause to command oracle not try cost base optimizator to probe data in source table

Comment: Looking at my data it appears that if the values of the string fields aren't valid (ex. `col6 = 08, col7 = 31, col8 = 2008`) then they are either `00|00|0000` or `0|0|0`?